# Save file in a specific folder

Tags: python, file, path, save

I would like to save a CSV file in a specific folder, but I can't find anywhere how to do it...
this is the code

```
# Writing on a CSV FILE
                fileToWrite = open(f"{userfinder}-{month}-{year}.csv', "a")
                fileToWrite.write('Subject,Start Date,Start Time,End Date,End Time,All Day Event,Description\n')
                fileToWrite.write(f'{string1}{tagesinfo2},{soup_datum},{soup_dienstbegin},{soup_datum},{soup_dienstende},,Kommentar: {soup_kommentar} Schiff: {b} Funktion: {soup_funktion} Schichtdauer: {soup_schichtdauer} Bezahlte Zeit: {soup_bezahltezeit} Mannschaft: {crew_list2}\n')
                fileToWrite.close()
                print(f'Datum: {soup_datum} Dienst: {string1}{tagesinfo2} --> Mannschaft: {crew_list2} --> OK')
```

Comment: `fileToWrite = open(f"{myPath}/{userfinder}-{month}-{year}.csv', "a")` where myPath is the path you want  `myPath="c:/foo/bar"`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the working directory with `os.chdir(path)`:

```
import os
path = '/Users/user/folder/example sub folder'
os.chdir(path)

#your code here
```

or, as mentioned in the comments, you can use:

```
myfolder = "c:/foo/bar/" 
fileToWrite = open(f"{myfolder}/{userfinder}-{month}-{year}.csv", "a")

#in this case the path is "{myfolder}/{userfinder}-{month}-{year}"
```

This option includes the path when opening (only affects the one file) whereas `os.chdir()` changes the directory for everything (what I use personally for all of my projects, which are small).
If you don't want to change your folder for all files created and read, use the second option; but when you want a python file to affect every file in a distant location I would use `os.chdir()`.